# Package installation error when new blank application in nanoframework is created

Tags: visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-extensions, nanoframework

When i try create new blank application in nanoframework, i get package installation error.

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7ezf.png)

It seems some problem in nanoframework visual studio extension, my version is NET nanoFramework VS2019 Extension v2019.5.0.8.vsix, but i also tried another versions with same problem.

I have visual studio 2019 community edition and i have installed almost all components.

When i press ok, project is loaded, but is not possible compile it, because there are missing all assemblies. When i try add assembly, theres nothing to add and add nuget packages from nanoframework store leads to error.

when i try this:

> pm> Install-Package nanoFramework.CoreLibrary.NoReflection -Version
> 1.10.1-preview.9

I get this error:

> NU1202: Package nanoFramework.CoreLibrary.NoReflection
> 1.10.1-preview.9 is not compatible with netnanoframework10 (.NETna noFramework,Version=v1.0). Package
> nanoFramework.CoreLibrary.NoReflection 1.10.1-preview.9 supports: net
> (.NETFramework,Version=v0.0)

similiar when i try another package versions.

So the extensions is installed incorectly, but i cant find why. i tried it more times. uninstall and install again. from extenstion store, and from disc. nothing successfull.

Comment: What is your Visual Studio version? e.g. 16.8.5.x

Comment: Also, have you followed this guide? https://docs.nanoframework.net/content/getting-started-guides/getting-started-managed.html

Comment: yes, i exactly followed this guide :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The webserver NuGet released today fixes the issues with the version mismatches.

The issue with VS2019 16.9 remains. Reported to VS Developer Community [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/nanoframework-templates-can-no-longer-be-created/1358051). Please up vote to help increase priority.

Answer (score 0):

What is the Community version you're using?

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019
Version 16.9.0

Answer (score 0):

After a little test, there seems to be an issue with the latest release of VS2019. A work around would be to:
Use V16.8.X

or

use an already created solution that you can edit.

or

add the required nuget to the project once it has been loaded (after the error):

[image]

Update: now fixed! it was due to a change to fix nuget, but caused an unintended consequence with nanoFramework.

Comment: i have tried open webserver.sample from nanoframework repository, but the references are broken and nuget packages is not possible install (the same error which i described in my question)
Package nanoFramework.CoreLibrary 1.7.3 is not compatible with netnanoframework10 (.NETnanoFramework,Version=v1.0). Package nanoFramework.CoreLibrary 1.7.3 supports: net (.NETFramework,Version=v0.0)

Comment: install visual studio V16.8.X solved problem for now. thank you.